# The request for procedure 'tblMyTable' failed because 'tblMyTable' is a table object

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2012

I have an excel workbook that uploads data into a sql database. The code has been working fine for the past year.

However today I am seeing the error message below. As far as I can tell nothing has changed.

```
The request for procedure 'tblMyTable' failed because 'tblMyTable' is a table object
```

The second line below is where the error occurs.

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "tblMyTable", pCn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Why is this no longer working?

Comment: Difficult to tell if it was working before. Is it affecting only this table? Just guessing here, but is it possible that permissions were changed on the server? Is the connection string still valid? If you use the connection string to download data in Excel, does it work?

Comment: i've tried another table and the code works. So it appears to be an issue with tblMyTable. Have no idea why though

Comment: Check your SQL Server for `tblMyTable`. Something is changed on RDBMS side.

Comment: Are you returning all fields from the tblMyTable? Is it a stored procedure? You may need to specify this with the CommandType parameter. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675946(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Are you seeing it after changing a value in that table? I am getting the same weird/wrong error message after setting a value in the table in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: ... oh never mind. I found that mine was because I had some text in the query highlighted, and then the Execute button was trying to run only the code I had highlighted, which was just a table identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the stored procedure still exists. Then also check to make sure a table wasn't created with the same name as your stored procedure. Common practice would be to name the stored procedure as "procMyTable." Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

maybe this solution is no longer useful to you, but I was facing the same error: *same conditions* and *same error*!
My solution was to run a script to see if this table was not already inserted in the database, and it was.
I used the following code for verification:

```
SELECT * FROM [your_database].[your_table]
GO
```